# React app doesn't start due problem with ReactDOMServer.renderToString() method

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I'm just learning React from the scratch and while following the course I've reached the problem with starting the app by `npm run dev:server command.` The console log returns:

```html
SyntaxError: C:/Users/woj/Desktop/moje/react env/src/server/server.js: Unexpected token (10:54)
   8 | 
   9 | server.get("/", (req, res) => {
> 10 |   const initialMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
     |                                                       ^
  11 | 
  12 |   res.send(`
  13 |     <html>
```

It's related with babel parser. Anyone can try to help me? Thanks from the advance.

server.js

```js
import express from "express";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import App from "../components/App";

const server = express();
server.use(express.static("dist"));

server.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const initialMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

  res.send(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Sample React App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="mountNode">${initialMarkup}</div>
        <script src="/main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});

server.listen(4242, () => console.log("Server is running..."));
```